# Why was this travel related post migrated to 3D printing?

Tags: bug, moderation, migration

I'm not arguing whether [this post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/uk-tier2-visa-resigned-and-rejoining-should-i-apply-for-a-visa-again) was on-topic on Travel or not, but it was migrated to 3D Printing, where it most definitely is not acceptable.  What happened, and what do we do to move it back?

> [image: Screen shot]

Comment: Proper credit goes to @bummi who brought it up.

Comment: 3d printing is the first site appearing on the list of migration targets. I'm guessing it was a mis-click: it was probably being migrated to expats. Closing it on 3d printing will reject the migration and it will come back here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened because I've made a mistake - it was supposed to be migrated to Expats.SE, however the mobile site glitched and redirected it to the first site on the list (3D printing) instead of the one I selected. We cannot do anything about it until the 3 D Printing mods bounce it back.

Comment: Thanks, will accept once I'm allowed to.

Comment: FYI I have cleared the migration history on our side and sent it to Expats. Now the 3d mods need to delete the orphaned question on their side.

Comment: And, in the process, the TSE upvotes and answer acceptance disappeared. The answer was accepted; why was it even touched? OP asked about visa application, not about emigration. I voted for you, Jonathan, but might you not be confusing your role as a mod and, perhaps, damaging it?

Comment: @Giorgio OP asked about Tier 2 visas and everything except General Visitor visas is off topic here when it comes to UK immigration.